# Bing Search Performance Keyword and Page Exports don't add up, should they?

Tags: bing, bing-webmaster-tools

If I examine a time period in the search performance tools for a period, the overview numbers are always an about order of magnitude greater than what I see when I download the keyword and pagee reports for the time period.

For example I might see 202K impressions and 7.5K clicks in the summary up top and when I download the CSV files they say 18K impressions and 250 clicks. This ratio is constant no matter what time period I choose.

Is this the expected behavior? Are the exported CSV reports samples? Is there another explanation, like perhaps manyy searches are anonymized.

Comment: Is there something I did not address? I notice the bounty is still out but you marked my answer accepted.

Comment: No. I thought I did award it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to replicate this on my end, the data doesn't add up. In addition, the data appears to come back in different orders depending on what page I click export from in the report's pagination.

From a product perspective, I believe it is fairly safe to assume that this phenomenon is not intended. Anonymized searches are quite possible, but there have also been documented issues with data quality on Bing's side.

Check out this [blog post](https://martijnscheijbeler.com/saving-bing-search-query-data-from-the-bing-webmaster-tools-api/) on gathering Bing Webmaster Tools data via API.  Here's the relevant quote:

> As I mentioned in the intro, the data quality is questionable and leaves very much up to the imagination. It’s one of the reasons why I wanted to share this script, so others can get their data out and we can hopefully learn more together on what the data represents. The big caveat seems that the data is exported at the time of extraction with a date range of XX days and it’s not possible to select a date range.

I really hate to say it, but I think that the answer to your question is simply "It's Bing". No offense to all of the Bing fans out there, of course.

That being said, I believe it is safe to say that the data exports from the Bing Web Master Tools performance report are not consistent or reliable. I would stick to analyzing reports in the dashboard, and take findings with a grain of salt *(did I do better or worse?)*.